# .htaccess redirect loop with RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a specific page

> `http://www.my.website/admin`

to

> `https://my.website/admin/`

using this code:

```
Redirect 301 /admin/ https://my.website/admin/
```

but it keeps looping and I can not find out why as I have specified the condition for 'www' not to be present.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tci\.rocks$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ https://my.website/admin/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WithoutWWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# END WithoutWWW

# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
   Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

How can i make this .htaccess stop looping ??

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\.website$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ https://my.website/admin/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i will choose yours as final answer next week when i test it. thank you

Comment: Ok, no problem !

Comment: i will now edit the question to reflex 100% what is on the live server, temporarily. then when all is clear, i will revert back to generic. thank you

Comment: can you please let me know if you have found a solution ??

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?